# jQuery click events makes problems when trying to ignore some childs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a problem with a click event:

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#dropdown", function () {
    showHide();
} ).find( "a" ).click( function ( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
} );


<div id="dropdown">
    <a href="https://google.de"></a> <- This should not trigger the click
</div>
```

After adding this to my JS file, I can't click anymore on any `<a>` element on my page. This happens because of my `e.stopPropagation()`.

What I originally wanted to do is to prevent calling my `showHide()` function when I click on any child link tag but binding it on the document with the selector inside the click function seems to be not working.

Does someone has a better idea?

Comment: Child link tag of what? the dropdown? Please elaborate using example.

Comment: @PrakharLondhe Yes, inside the dropdown.

Comment: Can you add some HTML to help us understand your setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the target of the click was an `<a>` element, and if it wasn't, proceed with `.showHide()`.

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#dropdown", function (event) {
    if(!(event.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'a')){
         showHide();
    }
} );
```

Comment: Why not doing !==?

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the selector so it only applies to child of `#dropdown`

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#dropdown", function () {
    showHide();
} ).find( "#dropdown > a" ).click( function ( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
} );
```